# In numpy, Python, how to conditionally rewrite part of an array, when the values I want to set are in an array of a different size?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have three arrays:

```
A[size1] of {0..size1}
B[size2] of {0..size1}
C[size2] of boolean
```

What I want:

```
for (int e = 0; e < size2; ++e) :
    if C[e] == some_condition, then B[e] = A[B[e]]
```

Since Python is slow, I have to implement it via numpy arithmetic on arrays. How can I do that?

Example:

```
A = np.array([np.random.randint(0,n,size1), np.random.randint(0,size1,size1)])
B = np.random.randint(0,size1,size2)
C = np.random.randint(0,n,size2)

#that's the part I want to do in numpy:
for i in range (size2) :
    if (C[i] > A[0][B[i]]) : 
        B[i] = A[1][B[i]]
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example to your question?

Comment: @Kasramvd Sure; I just did

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) -

```
mask = C > A[0][B] # Create mask to select valid ones from B
B[mask] = A[1][B[mask]] # Use mask to select and assign values
```

Comment: I have edited the question to show a more complicated problem, where I don't see how I could use masks. I may have simplified the question too much at the beginning.

Comment: The logic is much the same. The mask becomes `mask = C > A[0][B]`, and the assignment becomes `B[mask] = A[1][B[mask]]`

Comment: @Dunes Thanks! Edited the post with your suggestion.

Comment: @Jecke Check out the edits as suggested by Dunes, hope this gets closer to your actual use case :)

Comment: @Dunes , Divakar. Thanks a lot! That has made my program run twice as fast :)